# How can I remove a pattern in a ggplot2 fill category?

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

I am creating the following plot with `ggplot2`: 
[image: plot] 
- See the pattern that appears in the 'Other religions' category. It is not fully red.
- I think it must be because I used the `forcats::fct_other()` function to create the category.
- How can I remove the pattern?
Here is the code:

```
rel_wld %>%
  select(year, ends_with("gen")) %>%
  gather("religion", "value", -year) %>%
  mutate(religion = fct_other(religion, keep = rels,
                              other_level = "Other Religions")) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, fill = religion)) +
  geom_area(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 3) +
  theme_light()
```

Comment: Please can you include some data (use `dput(rel_wld)`) to help others reproduce your problem

Comment: You probably have non-unique `year` and `value` for the `"Other Religions"` category.

Comment: Yes, it worked! I grouped by year and value and summed the groups. Thank you both for the advices!